# ui-grid 4.2.0 Compatible with Angular 1.4.9?

Tags: bower, ui-grid

I'm using Angular 1.4.5 in my project. I updated my ui-grid version from 3.2.9 to 4.2.0. Now i'm getting the following note during bower update:

```
Please note that,
    angular-animate#1.4.9, angular-mocks#1.4.9, angular-sanitize#1.4.9, angular-touch#1.4.9 depends on angular#1.4.9 which resolved to angular#1.4.9
...
    angular-ui-grid#4.2.0 depends on angular#>=1.4.0 1.6.x which resolved to angular#1.6.9
Resort to using angular#1.4.9 which resolved to angular#1.4.9
Code incompatibilities may occur.
```

I think this is an error in the dependency handling, isn't it?

On the UI-Grid github page:

Angular Compatibility
UI-Grid is currently compatible with Angular versions ranging from 1.4.x to 1.6.x.

Can i use ui-grid 4.2.0 with angular 1.4.9?